# Automatic Session Refresh in Mobile App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking for a good design pattern for refreshing the session even if it gets expired from the web server.

Approach 1:
Login to the system and save the password. In the case of iOS app, can I save password in keychain. If so, what is the peculiarity of storing like that in iOS. After successful login, a token will be received in the app side. This token will be used for all the request sending(mobile app). If any of the request got failed due to session expiration, we can write separate function to regenerate the token based on the credential.

Approach 2:
Login to the system, and a token will be generated from the sever. The token will be sending to the client on all the response and client validates with old swell as new token. How to design the structure for automatic session refresh.

Sree

Comment: As far as I know,There is no automatic refresh session. You need to send another request if one is failed.

Comment: By the term automatic, I meant that I need to create a function block which can be generate a new token and retry the failed request with new access token. As I am not a web developer, i am not sure which is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The most common and best practice is for your api to issue a session token upon successful login from the client.

The mobile client can then store this locally(there is many methods of storage), in core data, in the defaults or even in the keychain(probably overkill).

The mobile client every time it makes a network request to the api, will contain the session token in the request, the server will then update this token expiry time(you could have it expire over 24hr period, 1 week, 1 month, etc).

The client should then react if the session token is expired by automatically logging out the user and presenting the login form.

Comment: But I don't want to take to login form, I have to generate new token in background without alerting the user and need to send the failed request. In this case, should I send the session token which the client is having. Can the api create a new token from the expired token and will it be link the user id?

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you want to, but in some cases you might actually want the user to re-login(say facebook expires a token and you need a new one from them). You have two options, 1 - have a session token that never expires, 2 - have a session token that expires but when it does, the client renews the session token by passing that back to the server and getting a new one.